# popTo does not work in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic3.

I develop E-commerce app.

If User has been Login Goto Shipping Page.

Then I click Navbar back button, Goto Login Page.

**But I need If user is authenticated Does not goto Login Page.**

Because I Assign a local variable.

Here is my code.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Shipping Address</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button  (click)="goback()" >
          <ion-icon class="customIcon" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>



goback()
  {
    console.log("HOBACK")
    if(this.Page == 'Signin')
    {
      this.navCtrl.popToRoot('CartPage');   
    }
  
  }
```

Page is a query params value.I just passed the value in nav.push().

My ques

**popToRoot** Does not work why?

Its also goto previous page(Backhistory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to redesign the login flow of you application. Here is what I suggest, Once user is logged in, instead of pushing the ShippingPage, set it as a root page. By doing this, you won't be seeing the back button on your shipping page after login.

e.g.

instead of `nav.push(ShippingPage);` do `nav.setRoot(ShippingPage);`

As far as `popToRoot` function is concerned, its working as defined by the documentation, i.e. it navigate back to the root of the stack which is LoginPage in your case.

Answer (score 0):

in Ionic popto method the parameter takes the index of the page not the name you import so just adding like

```
nav.popTo( this.navCtrl.getByIndex(1))
```

Try this;

Comment: You are wrong! Here is the method signature : 
`abstract popTo(page: Page | string | ViewController, params?: any, opts?: NavOptions, done?: Function): Promise<any>;`